# How to get rid of the ... at the output of the show command in Git

Tags: git, git-show

```
git show  --stat --pretty=format: 50c2ebc0e
```

Outputs:

```
 .git.ignore                                 |    2 +-
 .../WebServiceRequests/WebService.cs        |   78 ++++++++++----------
 .../UI/Bin/AjaxControlToolkit.omi           |    1 +
```

Is there a way to get the full path instead of those pesky 3 dots (...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like `--stat=180,150`. The numbers are: max width to take for the stat output, max width to use for the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you might use `git whatchanged` which puts the full paths on the end of the lines. This one is likely easier to parse if you get any filenames with spaces in.